# BehaviorSubject next()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I wanted to get a clear answer, because in Google I don't get what I want.

In this code:

```
titleSubject = new BehaviorSubject('');

setTitle(newTitle: string) {
    this.titleSubject.next(newTitle);

    this.titleSubject.pipe(
        debounceTime(500)
    ).subscribe( title => super.setTitle(title));
    
}
```

I have this service, which I call in some components. So I provide the service and call this method SetTitle().

The Question is:

With this code am I creating a new subscription every time I am calling it or I am listening to the same subscription every time I call this method?

What I want to do is set the title every time the method is called, with a debounceTime of 500.

This code works, but I don't want to create a new subscription every time the method is called!

Comment: You are using a finite observable that will get completed as soon as it is resolved. So every invocation will be like a fresh chapter where you start from scratch!

Comment: @AakashGoplani incorrect.

Comment: @bryan60 - please elaborate, why?

Comment: @AakashGoplani a `BehaviorSubject` is not finite and `debounceTime` doesn't make it finite.

Answer (score 2):

not totally sure what you're trying to accomplish here as I don't know what `super.setTitle` is referring to.. is this inheriting from a something with a subject as well as having a subject inside of it?

you are creating a new subscription every time the `setTitle` method is called. this code may seem to work, but it's actually calling `super.setTitle` the number of times you've called `setTitle`, so if you've run `setTitle` 5 times, on the 6th time, it will call `super.setTitle` 6 times.

you could just move your subscription to your constructor to only subscribe one time....

```
consrtructor() {
    super()
    this.titleSubject.pipe(
        debounceTime(500)
    ).subscribe( title => super.setTitle(title));
}
```

but there may be another subtle bug or possibly a memory leak in there depending on what your actual goals are and how this service really works.

Comment: I know the method is called every time i call it, i wanna know if i am creating a new subscribtion every time the method is called.
Because this is a Service

Comment: I need every time the method is called to listen to the same subscribtion, not create a new one everytime

Comment: you misunderstood. it is called THE NUMBER OF TIMES YOU PREVIOUSLY CALLED IT every time you call it. so on the 1st call it is called once, then on the second it is called two more times (3 total), then on the third it is called 3 more times (6 total) etc etc

Comment: as i said in my answer `you are creating a new subscription every time` and I provided a solution. absent more detail on your goals, I cannot go further.

Comment: i need my solution to be on that method, because that method is called on the components

Comment: The subscription you create in the constructor will persist and trigger when the class method triggers the subject. This is basic / fundamental rxjs

Comment: @Roffex: Bryan explained in great detail that _you are_ creating a _new_ subscription every time you call `setTitle`. Plus, given how a `BehaviorSubject` works, your `subscription` block will run n+1 times _every time_ when you call `setTitle`. The latter is very likely NOT what you want. Anyways, the original answer was answered, thus you can accept the answer and carry on with a new question, if you need further insight on how to possibly _improve_ your code.